# What's the difference between ipcs -lm and cat /sys/proc/kernel/xxxx

Tags: linux, memory-usage

I tried

ipcs -lm

```
------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 67108864
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 34359738368
min seg size (bytes) = 1
```

and

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmni
4096
cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax
68719476736
cat /proc/sys/kernel/shmall
8589934592
```

From the documentation I've read I understood they're describing the same values yet they're different. Can you please explain me what's the difference between them?

Cheers

Comment: I answer too quickly, I got same value for shmmax on ubuntu (not in Suse), but "wrong" value for shmall (in both ubuntu and suse). (which are in 2^64 range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, ipcs does read shared memory limits from `/proc`. Only if that fails does it fall back to using `shmctl()`.  And there is a `# define SHMMIN 1` as apparently that isn't in `/proc`.

- `/proc/sys/kernel/shmall` units are pages, ipcs converts `max total shared memory` to KB.
- `/proc/sys/kernel/shmmax` units are bytes, ipcs converts `max seg size` to KB.

The source code is the util-linux package, one mirror of which is at   https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/stable/v2.33/sys-utils/ipcs.c
  Notice that do_shm() does a page size unit conversion:

```
uint64_t tmp, pgsz = getpagesize();

tmp = (uint64_t) lim.shmall * pgsz;
```

(Because max total shared memory / shmall = page size, can tell your machine has 4 KB pages. Expected, that is extremely common.)